# AC-coupling capacitor destroys output signal?

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, buffer

As you can see I have designed a simple buffer circuit with a current source. The output is nice and steady as you can see (\$V = 2.6+1.6\sin(2\cdot\pi\cdot 1000\cdot t)\$ is the input, frequency of 1kHz). The current source provides 1mA.

[image]
[image]

However, when I add a capacitor between the output node and the 8-ohm resistor to function as a dc offset remover, the output gets defaced. The value of the capacitor I added was **1 microfarad**.
[image]
[image]

At first I thought maybe the capacitor and resistor form a high-pass filter on the output node and that's why my signal got distorted, but changing the value of capacitor absolutely did not help and my output was still distorted. This is the output for a **2microfarad** value.

[image]

So I wanted to **1)** ask about the reason for this, since I've been using coupling capacitors at the output of my circuits and never had this problem before, and **2)** is there any fix to it? That 8-ohm resistor is actually a speaker, and thus no dc offset should be applied to it, is there any alternative dc-offset removing methods I can use in my circuit?

Comment: You forgot to say what value capacitor you used and what your -3 dB low-frequency cut-off point specification is. Please [edit].

Comment: @Transistor Sorry, I have added the value of capacitors in the body of the text.

Comment: A capacitor between the output and the 8Ohm resistor would an AC coupling cap. So I suspect some error in phrasing. Could you just add the cap to the schematic as well?

Comment: Isn't the output only capable of sinking 0.6mA because of the set current value? Which means the most negative the output voltage can be is -4.8mV. Which seems to match what you see in your second graph.

Comment: @HorrorVacui I have added the new schematic (after adding the capacitor) to my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without the output capacitor the top transistor supplies all the current to the 8 ohm load. It is an emitter follower and this configuration is ideal for this type of drive. The lower transistor hardly plays any role in this circuit and you could actually remove it and get virtually identical results.

When you use a capacitor in series with the 8 ohm load, things change considerably. Now the lower transistor is expected to remove charge from said capacitor when the input signal is at its trough or most negative peak. However, the current sinking capabilities of the lower transistor (configured as a weak current sink) means that it can't do this to any degree comparable with the top emitter follower transistor's ability to source current.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation! Are there any npn-based circuits that I can use for a better current sink?

Comment: @Work you need to lower RE quite a lot. Try aiming for 10 ohms and see if you get a decent improvement but don't expect miracles with this type of configuration. If you do get RE at 10 ohms you might find that the two bias resistors need to reduce by a factor of ten. Of course you could just simulate the circuit to save a lot if fuss.

Comment: This is a classical class A audio amp, you need the current sink to sink the full scale current that flows in the load (250mA if swinging an 8 ohm load +-2V), make that 1k emitter load more like 4R and use power transistors on modest heatsinks. Efficient class A is NOT!

Comment: Clear Yoda speak is also not. I think you mean "Class A is NOT efficient!"

Comment: Understand, what was said, I did.